# Why is the script jollywallet is showing and why is that used for

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I have tried to google and found no much information about that.

In one site i found saying it is a kind of Virus.

```
<code>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/client?dist=111&amp;sub=1"></script> 
</code>
```

And it also display the other tag as

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript" id="jw_00" src="http://d2cnb4m0nke2lh.cloudfront.net/jollywallet/resources/js/2/affiliate_client.js"></script>
</code>
```

Comment: What is the context of this, have you found it on your own web site?

Comment: Yes, i found it on a website [link](http://seleniumeasy.com), which is showing a script in head tag. And i want to know why that script is coming and if it is not needed i need to remove it.

Comment: Hmm, it may be some legitimate form of cash back program, I'm not sure. But then, it really seems strange in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is MalWare.  When I removed the Firefox Add-On "The weDownload Manager" the script was no longer injected into the header of my page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution helped me to fix the issue :).

Comment: Yes it is a malvare. Get rid of these addons as fast as possible before they steal your bank credentials or other personal informations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Chrome and have same issu from "Webpage Screenshot".

Thanks @SukieC your idea, and I found the way deactive this without uninstall this extension :

- Open extention page
- Click on "Option" link of "Webpage Screenshot" extension
- In new page opened, click "Advanced" link at end of page. It open an option "Enable anonymous usage statistics", uncheck this, and click "Done" button.